# Terraform Error while creating AWS Cognito Userpool

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws

Below is my terraform code to create a Cognito Userpool.

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "sample_application" {
    name = "sampletest-pool"
    schema {
            name                    = "email"
            attribute_data_type     = "String"
            required                = true
            string_attribute_constraints {
            }
    }
    schema {
            name                    = "name"
            attribute_data_type     = "String"
            required                = true
            string_attribute_constraints {
                min_length = 1
                max_length = 50
            }
    }
    schema {
            name                    = "family_name"
            attribute_data_type     = "String"
            required                = true
            string_attribute_constraints {
                min_length = 1
                max_length = 50
            }
    }
    schema {
            name                     = "phone_number"
            developer_only_attribute = true
            attribute_data_type      = "Number"
            required                 = true
            number_attribute_constraints {}
    }
}
```

When I give `terraform apply` I'm displayed with the below error.

> ╷ │ Error: error creating Cognito User Pool:
> InvalidParameterException: You can not change AttributeDataType or set
> developerOnlyAttribute for standard schema attribute phone_number │ │
> with aws_cognito_user_pool.sample_application, │   on cognito.tf line
> 1, in resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "sample_application": │    1:
> resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "sample_application" { │ ╵

I know I'm making a small mistake but unable to find it and the official docs don't have any example for this usecase at all.
**Official Docs:** https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool

Comment: The error is about `aws_cognito_user_pool.toggle_application`. This is not the resource you provided in the question.

Comment: @Marcin Just now updated the error message. `toggle` is an internal application name in my workplace. Didn't want it to expose it here. That's why changed it in the terraform code but forgot to change it in the error. Hope this clears out the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says you cannot set developerOnlyAttribute for standard schema attributes ([Standard Atrtibutes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html) )

Also phone number attribute_data_type should be string and cannot be changed.

```
 schema {
            name                     = "phone_number"
            attribute_data_type      = "String"
            required                 = true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually when I removed the `developerOnlyAttribute` I still got the same error but then it was the other mistake that you pointed out. I changed `data_type` to String and it worked. The error message was slightly misleading.